# Can not set `alias` property on graphql request intercept

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, cypress, end-to-end

I'm using Cypress to intercept requests made to a graphql api.
But for some reason, the alias that I'm setting is just not there.

```js
export const hasOperationName = (
  req: { alias?: string; body?: any },
  operationName: string
) => {
  const { body } = req;
  return (
    body.hasOwnProperty("operationName") && body.operationName === operationName
  );
};

// Alias query if operationName matches
export const aliasQuery = (
  req: { alias?: any; body?: any },
  operationName: string
) => {
  if (hasOperationName(req, operationName)) {
    req.alias = `gql${operationName}Query`;
    console.log(req);
  }
};
```

This is basically the example code that is given in the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/working-with-graphql#Alias-multiple-queries-or-mutations).

And in my `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.goToHomePage();
  aliasQuery('myGraphQLQueryName');
});
```

When I `console.log(req)` the object has no alias property and if it got into that `if` statement, it should have.
So basically, no alias is being set apparently:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried inserting a console.log statement inside `hasOperationName` to check if any request bodies have the operation name `'myGraphQLQueryName'`? This could be a nice sanity check to make sure the problem is where you think it is.

Comment: Your aliasQuery function requires a request object, but you don't pass it in. Where do you think the function will get it from?

The docs show the following usage:
cy.intercept('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/graphql', (req) => {
      // Queries
      aliasQuery(req, 'GetLaunchList')